# Creating a workbook based database-calculations-display system in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, database, power-query

I'm trying to make an Excel based modular reporting system so that each sections can be modified without messing up everyone else's reports.

INPUT / Facts table: I have a database that is currently Excel based, I don't want users touching it. Assume it updates itself automatically.

OUTPUT / Display: I have a number of Excel based reports / dashboards all in separate documents.

PROCESS / Calculations: In between these two ends of my system I want to put in a sheet that performs calculations on my facts tables from the database. I'll use Power Query to pull everything together and create the calculations. Why? well a number of basic metrics will be common to each report so why not just define them once and let the reports pull them out rather than reinvent the same calculations on every reporting workbook?

However for end users that just want to update their reports, updating each individual report is easy. However, I don't have an elegant solution for forcing the calculations sheet to update. I could put VBA on the reports or I could ask everyone to open and update the calculations sheet. Both seem....less than optimal.

Is there a best practice for this sort of thing? Should I not even have a calculations workbook and just let everyone make a PQ query straight into the 'database'?

Comment: I think there are two things two consider 1) what is the PQ ability level of "everyone" and 2) having PQ do some intermediate process (even within the same workbook) could cause some refresh issues for other workbooks. I would try to only have one combined "source/computation" workbook, and maybe provide a template workbook for end users with some predefined PQ. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Query ribbon (with your Calculations table selected), in the Properties pop-up you can choose **Refresh data when opening the file**. That will run that query every time the file opens.